# Spring boot not able to download spring parent group dependies

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are not able to download spring boot parent releated jars.
We are facing 501 error.

Because maven has stopped it's support for http protocol
We have mentioned https url in pom file but still it is pointing to http link

Comment: Post your pom file

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Check your maven `settings.xml` file. Usually this can be found in your home directory under `.m2/settings.xml`. You are probably pulling from repositories listed there.

That file will contain profiles that include repository URLs.

Comment: @SunilHiray in that case post your pom.xml, your settings.xml and the whole error. Don't have enough info to help you.